# Не работает отправка данных из textarea tinymce

Tags: php, javascript

Ребзя,всем доброго времени суток.
На сайте есть textarea,данные из нее записываю в бд,установил редактор tinymce,и из-за него теперь не работает скрипт отправки данных,в чем может быть проблема?
Если ставлю стандартную textarea,то все работает.
Сам код редактора:

```
 tinymce.init({
        selector: '#text',
        height:250,
        language : "ru",
        theme: 'modern',
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
            'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect| bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify ' +
        '| bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
        image_advtab: true
    });
```

Comment: Что именно и как не работает,  каков код отправки данных? откуда ? из textarea  которому прицеплен?  tinymce.get('your_textarea_id').getContent(); - это нужно?

Comment: @Swift та,когда особого нет,просто через Post передаю данные из textarea.Без js'a.

Comment: Я может чего--то не понимаю, что не получается. но если используется tinymce, то он хранит текст в себе (в общем, обладая возможностью фильтровать вывод, например, убирая концы строк  и т.п.) и обрабатывает события  textarea

Comment: Приведенного кода тут недостаточно, нужна минимальная обвязка показывающая реализацию (которая не работает). Очень часто при этом и выявляется ошибка (забыто описание метода формы например?)  А то  всем отвечающим придется создавать свою страницу, и обнаружив, что у них все работает, гадать, что же в  варианте Оп было забыто или сделано неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

Данных в вопросе недостаточно для точного ответа. Скорее всего, что-то некорректно подключено или подключено не в том месте. Возможно, надо поменять `selector: '#text'` на `selector: "textarea"`.

Попробуйте убрать все относящееся к Tiny MCE из своего кода и перед закрывающим тегом `</head>` поставить следующее:

```
  <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
          tinymce.init({
              selector: "textarea",
              plugins: [
                  "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                  "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                  "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
              ],
              toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
          });
  </script>
```

Обязано работать. Кто не верит - может проверить https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmOKqM

Comment: К сожалению, ваш код так же не работает :С
Немного не понял,какие еще данные нужны?
На textarea установлен id="#text",по нему он и определяет.Больше вроде и него нет,а отправка данные просто происходит через $_POST.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmOKqM

Answer (score 0):

Перед отправкой:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

Сталкивался с такой проблемой - помогло.
Более подробно здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122085/jquery-and-tinymce-textarea-value-doesnt-submit

Вот исправлено под твою форму:

```
$('#text').closest('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Просто добавь этот код на страницу, должно заработать.

Comment: У меня отправка осуществляется без js'a.Тоесть просто php,метод $_POST.Как я понимаю,нужно обязательно задействовать еще и js?

Comment: tinymce сам по себе работает на js, т.е. нужно сделать и отпраку на js.
Попробуйте сделать так: $('form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); tinyMCE.triggerSave(); $(this).submit(); });

Comment: где 'form' - это тег вашей формы, но лучше использовать id формы, это для наглядности. Здесь написано, что перед отправкой нужно выполнить это действие, а только потом отправить (в коде выше).
В общем выше исправил, попробуй.

Comment: Ругается на первую строчку :С
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
Сейчас только заметил,в консоле вылезает ошибка 
"An invalid form control with name='content' is not focusable.",что означает,не знаете?

Comment: Первая строчка - не подключена, либо подключается ниже по дереву jQuery-библиотека. Если же не хотите jQuery - можно этот код переписать на чистый js. Вторая строчка - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable

Comment: добавил к форме просто <form name="myform" novalidate>
Все добавляет,только смайлы,жирный,курсивный шрифт не добавляет.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Все зависит от построения... triggerSave  сохраняет все коллекции, нужно при отправке формы, однако есть сценарии где он не поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393512/tinymce-textarea-and-post-form-using-ajax